# Null param value on form submit grails

Tags: grails, checkbox

I have one checkbox(id, name:**checkedEx**) in grails  gsp list and have sortableColumn where I pass checkbox value in params map. Now when I click any of the sortable column, the checkbox gets checked, as the query string gets the value localhost:8080/api-name/list.gsp?checkedEx=null (this null value sets the checkbox)

```
<g:checkBox name="checkedEx" id="checkedEx" value="${checkedEx}" onclick="this.form.submit();" />

<g:sortableColumn property="date" title="date" params='["checkedEx":"${checkedEx}"]' />
```

How to check if the value of checkedEx is null , then in sortableColumn send param checkedEx as empty.

Thanks!

Comment: at null value you want to check box checked or unchecked?

Comment: at null value I want to uncheck the checkbox..@user1791574

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on the same line like this:

```
<g:sortableColumn ... params='["checkedEx":"${checkedEx?checkedEx:''}"]' />
```

or use a

```
<g:if>     tag and <g:set> if you want to do more than use the operator
```

Comment: I tried first solution. But then whenever I check the box manually after clicking the sortable column, everytime the checkbox gets unchecked.